# Make an overlay hidden on page load in Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation

Using [this article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html#animating-ng-show-ng-hide) I made an overlay div fade in/out on mouse click with ng-hide/ng-show. It works fine except one small thing - when page is loading and not all Angular is loaded yet, the overlay flickers for a moment then fades out when Angular loads respective variables that are in charge for overlay visibility.

The div looks like this in Jade:

```
.overlay(ng-show="overlayStatus=='on'", ng-init="overlayStatus='off'", ng-animate="'fade'")
```

Now to remove that flickering, and make the overlay hidden on load without Angular evaluations, I add `style="display:none;"` to this div and it seems to fix the issue. Though I am not sure if it's a proper way to do this.

Please advise.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that, though a CSS class might be better than inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) directive

Comment: It doesn't work because needs Angular to set `overlayStatus` to `off` and before that it still shows that div for a moment.